# Getting "Access is denied." when trying to update UserPrincipal object

Tags: c#, sharepoint, active-directory, sharepoint-2013, directoryservices

I have a SharePoint solution with a custom application where a user should be able to change some properties in his own Active Directory object.

I am doing the following:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = ActiveDirectory.GetPrincipalContext("lab");
UserPrincipal user = ActiveDirectory.GetUserPrincipal(ctx, "Administrator");

user.DisplayName = user.DisplayName + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmss");
user.Save();
```

I am logged in to SharePoint as the domain administrator and i am trying to change my own DisplayName.

What is wrong with my code?

**Update 20.04.2016**

I have built a small Console Application with the following code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "lab");
            UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "administrator");

            DirectoryEntry de = (user.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry);

            user.DisplayName = user.DisplayName + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmss");
            user.Save();

            Console.WriteLine("OK");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

This works fine! That means normally, that the Authentication goes wrong or the user which is logged into SharePoint is not getting used to connect to AD and do the changes. If this could be the case, how could i find out with which user i am doing the operation?

**Update 20.04.2016 - 2**

I have now tried to put the username and password in the PrincipalContext contructor as below:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "lab", "administrator", "pass");
```

This works, too! That means now definitely, that the user which is logged in to SharePoint is not used to create the PrincipalContext. But why? **Normally code is always executed in the context of the current user!?**

How can i find out which user is used to create the PrincipalContext and how can i change it that the logged in user is getting used?

Comment: Try to inspect Thread.CurrentPrincipal

Comment: @Yev... This gives me back the `Administrator`. Which i am expecting. But i found this on the web http://sharepoint-tweaking.blogspot.de/2007/12/impersonation-in-aspnet-causes.html which says: This is caused by the fact that when a user is authenticated against a sharepoint server using NTLM or Kerberos, a "secondary token" is sent to the server that it uses to authenticate the user. This token cannot be used to authenticate the current user against another server (e.g. a domain controller). But i am on the same machine (Sharepoint and AD ist on one server).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I resolved it like this:

1. In IIS, in the advanced settings of my app -> In Identity I add my service account (example: domain\service-account)
2. In my active directory, I give to this service account full control on folder and sub-folder where I want to create/update user (you need to modify view to see security tab -> right click -> view -> advanced features)
3. If you already have that, check if your service account is not disabled

And now everything is working :)